# apk is not compatible with this device .. and supported device 0

Tags: android, apk, compatibility, android-install-apk

you can check this URl and image

[image]

[enter link description here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mtma.mytripmyadventure)

```
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES
```

i only use 8 permission .. how can i resolve it ?

Comment: Could you list the features you use?

Comment: this is my feature ... need manifest ? 

    android.hardware.CAMERA2
    android.hardware.FAKETOUCH
    android.hardware.LOCATION
    android.hardware.location.GPS
    android.hardware.location.NETWORK
    android.hardware.screen.PORTRAIT
    android.hardware.WIFI

Comment: please add device configuration and your manifest code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Try adding the android support screen option in manifest

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
                  android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
                  android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
                  android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
                  android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

2. Also try adding `uses feature` and uses permission tag, sometimes google play makes your app incompatible due to that. and also if you app requires those future set the requirement to `true`.